# Smile Elastic search extension does not working in custom theme Magento 2.3

Tags: magento2.3, catalogsearch, elasticsearch

I have installed smile elasticsearch extension and i am using Magento 2.3.
Everything configured fine from server side and admin side both.

If i enabled luma theme from backend and check for elasticsearch then it it work fine.Please check below screenshot.

[image]

But when i enabled third party theme(i am using clue theme) and check for elasticsearch then it does not working properly.Please check below screenshot.

[image]

Comment: you can contact elastic suppot team

Comment: Check this out https://github.com/Smile-SA/elasticsuite/issues/79

Comment: Please check in the custom theme, Is layout defining that set the Block to Magento's default search.